# utf8 encoding issue with discord node.js and mysql for 4-byte characters

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a case where I am trying to get the name from a discord channel.  I use:

```
message.channel.name
```

and this works just fine, except for 4-byte encoded names, typically things like some Asian language characters, and some emojis.  as an example:

```
sports (fails)
¡§™sports (works)
```

Here is an example from my Windows PowerShell(v7) output of my sql insert error:

```
INSERT INTO serverdata (channel_name, isChannelActive) VALUES ('sports',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channel_name='sports', isChannelActive = 1
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^
Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8F\x80sp...' for column 'channel_name' at row 1
```

Powershell puts up the "?" for the basketball, but I think this is just a console issue and not related to my execution flow.

I have chased through much of the internet searches...all my files are encoded for UTF8(mb4 where possible to specify), I use VS Code to edit.

I believe I have no place where UTF8MB3 is being used.  I also can take the exact SQL string, put it in the MYSQL workbench, and execute a script directly, and the syntax works fine.  This leads me to believe it is some kind of interaction between discord and node.js?

Any advice?  TIA!

***Code source in JS that shows the issue***

```
    var tempBuf = message.channel.name;
//    var tempBuf = Buffer.from(message.channel.name);
//    var tempBufLen = tempBuf.write(message.channel.name);
//    var tempBufLen = tempBuf.length + 1;
//    tempBuf = tempBuf.toString('utf8',0,tempBufLen)
//    tempBuf = tempBuf.toLocaleString();
//    console.log("buffer : " + `${tempBuf}`);
//    console.log("buffer length : " + tempBufLen);
//    console.log("buffer (len) character : " + tempBuf.toString('utf8', 0, tempBufLen));

    // insert into the server database
    let sql = (`INSERT INTO serverdata (channel_name, isChannelActive) VALUES ('${tempBuf}',${onOrOff}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channel_name='${ tempBuf}', isChannelActive = ${onOrOff}`);
    console.log(sql)

    // execute the insert statment
    connection.query(sql, function (err) { if (err) throw err });
```

Comment: Are you trying to use node.js or powershell? Please post the code that causes the problem in your js code.

Comment: Technical, but important, note about UTF8:  there is no such thing as "mb3" or "mb4" UTF8. Whe whole "mb..." thing is a ridiculous bit of mysql column type naming, caused by mistakes they made in the past (and are still making, because once unicode codepoints, encoded using UTF8, start needing 5 bytes we'll be right back to "and now it doesn't work in mysql" and they'll no doubt come up with mb6 or some such nonsense). UTF8 is simply UTF8, it is a variable length encoding.

Comment: check if all part have uft8mb4 connection tables...

Comment: @Bergi :I am technically using both.  I'm launching node from PS.  The above is my output from PS of my JS code.  I'm adding in the JS function where it fails, including some ways that I was playing around with seeing if there were forced type conversions needed.

Comment: I also moved to PS Core, in case there was some issues with default behavior in PS-V5 for windows.  no change.  Node is v14.16.1, and again...if I take the output (from the console log dump of the sql) and load it in mysql in a query tab, it works fine.  MYSQL seems to be setup correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require emoji support, ensure each `MySQL` table that includes them is configured with `CHARSET=utf8mb4`. You will also need to ensure your connection config in the `node` app includes the related option with matching value.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  user: process.env.DB_USER || 'local_user',
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'local_password',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'local_database',
  charset: 'utf8mb4' // necessary for emoji character support
});
```

Comment: ok despite all the issues with ensuring my database and tables are utf8mb4, I didn't have this charset variable in mysql connection.  adding this, my code works flawlessly.  thanks @dusthaines!

Comment: You're welcome. I had the same issue and it's not well documented that the charset option must be included even if the charset of table to query is correct. Since it is the default charset I use, I make sure to [always include it as part of my connection template](https://github.com/dusthaines/mysqljs_setup_snippet/blob/master/app.js)